# Silverlight passing data to aspx page

Tags: .net, silverlight, asp.net

I want to send data from my silverlight application to a aspx page.  But i don't want to pass parameter in the url when calling the aspx page.

So i figure the best way is to do a POST. But i'm not too sure how to do it..  Those anybody know.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804250/passing-parameters-from-silverlight-to-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at:

[Passing parameters from silverlight to ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804250/passing-parameters-from-silverlight-to-asp-net)