# How to get textbox value from Silverlight, into aspx page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have defined a TextBox in Silverlight UserControl (at MainPage.xaml), and I have used it in an aspx page. Now I need to get value of the TextBox in my aspx page.
How can I access it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 4 options:

1. InitParams.
2. QueryStrings.
3. Using HtmlPage.Document.
4. Using Object Serialization.

The solution is at the following post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/brijmohan/archive/2011/06/22/passing-parameters-between-silverlight-and-asp-net-part-1.aspx

also read also the following:

[Passing parameters from silverlight to ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804250/passing-parameters-from-silverlight-to-asp-net)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233915/Passing-parameters-between-Silverlight-and-ASP-NET
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/21071.aspx

Comment: Options 1 and 2 are only useful going from ASPX to Silverlight. The question was how to go the other way (use the Silverlight TextBox value from inside the hosting ASPX page).

Comment: How about other 3 options? Are they useful for passing data from silverlight to aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get value from silverlight into aspx page is via `InitParams`.

Comment: `InitParams` is used to move data *from* ASPX *into* Silverlight. The question asked was how to go the other way (Silverlight to ASPX). I'm afraid your answer is not useful.